Simply adding a CustomEditor to a ScriptableObject causes weird inspector behavior
I have a scriptable object that holds a list of 200 items. Before adding any sort of custom editor to the scriptable object, the inspector looks like this

Now simply adding an empty custom editor to the script, it causes the inspector to render like this

The list editor no longer has a scroll bar and instead the full list renders in the inspector. Which causes quite a bit of lag for a 200 item list.
My custom editor is empty like so
public override async void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();
}


Seems that the base.OnInspectorGUI() uses the old school drawer for lists (now ReorderableList is the "new" default) .. have you tried using DrawDefaultInspector instead?

@derHugo Thats interesting. DrawDefaultInspector() did not fix it unfortunately.

hm it might be related to Unity having switched over to use UIToolkit (UXML + CSS based VisualElement) as the new standard for Editor GUI ... I wonder if this is fixed if you used the UIToolkit way instead (see e.g. here)
